# Escaping text for regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, escaping

In Perl, there's a function named `quotemeta` which accepts a string and returns a regex pattern that matches that string. It's used in virtually every program to avoid [code injection bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

One would use `quotemeta` when dynamically building a pattern. For example,

```
"^"+quotemeta(var)+"_\\d+$"
```

A JavaScript implementation follows:

```
function quotemeta(s) {
   return String(s).replace(/\W/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Given how needed this function when working with regex patterns, I would have expected JavaScript to provide one. Does JavaScript or jQuery already have such a function?

Comment: @p.s.w.g, I already know it's possible to write a custom solution. My question is whether there already exists one in JS or jQuery. I looked, but I want to double check. Not a duplicate.

Comment: As you say, Perl's quotemata is `[^\w]`. This is actually dangerous if the text is to be injected into a regex. Its better to escape the 12 meta non-class and 4 meta class characters instead, that is if its going to a part of a regex string.

Comment: @sln, backwards. Far safer to escape anything that might ever need escaping (whitelist) rather than figuring out exactly what needs to be escaped in every implementation (blacklist).

Comment: Why do we need to double escape a string intended to be used as a RegEx? Just compile the expression from the string like: `var re = new RegExp('^'+string+'$', 'gi');` Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @tenub, Say `string` is `a*b`, `new RegExp('^'+string+'$', 'gi')` matches `a*b`, which `new RegExp('^'+quotemeta(string)+'$', 'gi')` matches `aaaaaab`. Not the same.

Comment: @tenub, its a literal he's injecting. But it can ONLY be a literall, the entire string including spaces control codes, everything.

Comment: @ikegami, `new RegExp('^'+string+'$', 'gi')` matches `aaaaaab` as well.

Comment: @tenub, I said it backwards. I meant: Say string is `a*b`, `new RegExp('^'+string+'$', 'gi')` matches `aaaaaaab`, while `new RegExp('^'+quotemeta(string)+'$', 'gi')` matches `a*b`. Not the same.

Comment: I am still of the mind that escaping all non-word char's to make literals should be avoided in general. The notion of a `\W` literal is not correct in all engines. Posix for one, and hybrids, for example `\<` and `\>` are word boundries, not literals. But, JS does not have these problems I guess.

Comment: @sln, That's a different regex language and thus irrelevant. Even the one linked above wouldn't work for POSIX regex patterns. It's impossible to write a function that escapes for any language. In Perlish regex languages such as JS's, unescaped word characters match literally and escaped non-word characters match literally. Some unescaped non-word characters also match literally, but using a list of them is needlessly complicated and it's not forward-compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have such a method natively. (And jQuery doesn't include one)

Usually, when searching for a string pattenr, you'd use [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). This method find a string in a string, so you won't even need to convert the string pattern to a regex.

`String.prototype.replace` can also take a String pattern.

It is not exactly the same but it'll work for most string matching use cases.

Comment: You'd use `quotemeta` when building a pattern (e.g. `"^"+quotemeta(var)+"_\\d+\\z"`)

Comment: Sure, it is not the same. I was pointing to a potential solution which work for most of the use cases.